# Кэширование статики nginx.

Tags: nginx, http, кэширование, http-заголовки

В конфиге прописано

```
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|pdf|ppt|txt|bmp|rtf|js)$ {
        set $root_path /var/www/airbluetooth/data/www/адрес_сайта;
        root $root_path;        
        expires 3d; 
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
    etag on;
```

Обновляю страницу все равно статус кода идет 200ок.  Что еще нужно добавить?

Comment: покажи полный конфиг nginx и заголовки ответа сервера

Comment: проблема решилась так: location ~* .(json|woff2|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
      expires max; 
      log_not_found off; 
      access_log off;
      sendfile   on;
      tcp_nopush on;
      sendfile_max_chunk 400k;
   
 }